# How to disable or delete guest user account from my MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, mac, macbook

In "Users and Groups", I see a "Guest User" listed there as "Login only". However I do not want this user account. When I try to uncheck the "Allow guests to login this computer" for this user, I found that checkbox is greyed out.

So how can I disable or delete the guest user from my Macbook?

I have FileVault and Find my Mac enabled, but even after I disabled them, that checkbox is still grey out!

The reason I want to disable or delete guest user is that I found the process parentalcontrolsd occupies a lot of CPU, I searched and found it seems to fix it I need to disable or delete guest user.

Comment: I added a new idea to my answer...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it's greyed out - assuming you are running from an admin account & have unlocked the padlock, bottom left, then you should have control over the guest account.

However, if it shows Login only, then parental control is off for that account, otherwise it would say Enabled, Managed.

[image]

BTW, Admin accounts, by definition, cannot have parental controls enabled, so if the process is running, then maybe check any non-admin accounts too.

One late thought - make sure the guest account isn't currently logged in - try Fast User Switching & log it out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help but better try it for you to know.

Try activating back your filevault, never mind the find my mac, and then go to the Users and Groups. Now, click the Guest User, be sure that the lock is unlocked and after that uncheck the "Allow guests to log in to this computer". After successfully unchecking the Guest User you can go back and disable the filevault.

Note: If the filevault is not working try clicking the firewall instead of the filevault then do the process again listed above.